# Get css element inside an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I know there is a same-origin policy with iframe but I would like to know if it's possible by a way to get an element or his css by clicking it through the iframe.

The website inside it would be an external domain from my server, so I guess it's impossible to do it but I ask you even.

Thank you.

Comment: Not impossible just challenging, if you have control of both parent and child page use CORS if your server is capable (S3 does). postMessage API is always an option.